# Short story: robot butler helps elderly man decide when to commit suicide

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

A paperback short story collection I read in the 1992-2002 era included a story in which a man was sinking into dementia.  Appreciating that the progressive nature of the disease would make it hard for him to recognize the right time, he programmed a robot butler with his values and memories.  He secretly assigned the butler to help him choose a time to commit suicide that would be early enough that he would still be capable of doing so on his chosen terms, but late enough that his quality of life was below his target threshold.  His wife thought it was just a routine robotic household/professional servant.

Story was probably written 1980-1995, and probably published in an SF periodical before being collected into a PB collection.  Collection was probably author-centric, rather than theme-centric.  I think it's on my shelves somewhere, but asking here is faster than skimming all my shelves volume by volume.

Comment: What does "_PB_" stand for when you say a "_PB short story collection_"? I am not familliar with the term

Comment: What @fez, you mean to tell us you _don't_ own a peanut butter collection?

Comment: Probably it means "paperback".

Comment: Any self-respecting reader has their own sandwich collection.  I sort mine by color.

Comment: I think I remember this from Asimov's magazine - the butler gave him a gun when the time was right, correct?

Comment: Thank you to whoever was kind enough to expand my abbreviation of paperback.  You get a peanut butter sandwich!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Living Will](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41618) by Alexander Jablokov, perhaps.  This was published in Asimov's in 1991 and in the The Year's Best Science Fiction: Ninth Annual Collection in 1992.

This [review](https://marzaat.com/2018/03/23/living-will/) says:

> A very poignant story built around a simple premise: what if you could
> encode a simulation of your personality into a piece of software and
> let it make the decision when a disease had changed you so much (here
> Alzheimers) your old, encoded self wouldn’t want to go on living and
> burdening others and would tell you to kill yourself?

It's available [here](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v15n07_1991-06/page/n71/mode/2up)

Quote from near the climax of the story:

> “Get the plastic sheet,” the computer commanded.
>
> “What?”
>
> “The plastic sheet. It’s under the back porch where you put it.”
>
> “I don’t remember any plastic sheet.”
>
> “I don’t care if you remember it or not. Go get it  and bring it in here.”
>
> Obediently, clumsily, Roman dragged in the heavy roll of plastic and spread it out on the study floor in obedience to the computer’s instructions.
>
> With a loud click the secure drawer slid open. Roman reached in and pulled out the pistol. He stared at it in wonder.

Comment: i like the simulation's impatience.

Comment: It needs to get this done while the guy can still follow directions - and the computer is based on the guy's personality, so he's probably an impatient guy

Comment: If I mention Back to the Future, can you think of a sort of related scene? (II or III, not I)

Comment: Nobody calls me chicken?

Comment: No, it was how the decrepit but wiser Biff treats his younger self, actually bullying himself as he would Marty's dad -- sort of poignant, really. Wiser, yet still incapable of communicating in a civil way, even with himself. A lot to those flicks, I thinks.

Comment: Oh yeah - that's from II, not III: I thought you were looking for something in both

Comment: I would add that in almost all stories of duplicates, there is caution at least if not murderous hostility between the original and his clones. An exception of course if future and past selves where the future self almost always tries desperately to help the younger self take a better path.

Comment: @Andrew, you get the shiny prize!  Thank you!  That is exactly the story I remember.

Comment: And voila! There it was on my shelf, in the theme-centric paperback collection titled 'Hackers', from 1996, as listed in sfdb, that @Andrew included.